# Missing "Resource Dictionary" in menu "Add item" in VSTO solution

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

In Ms Word I'm trying to add TaskPane with WPF controls.
I know that I have to add host winforms control to taskpane and later add wpf contorls to this host.
Its works for me and everythig works.

But when I want to properly add pretty wpf control using resource dictrionary I cant, bacause there isnt't resource dictrionary on list to add from "Add->New Item..." menu.

There is no problem with other wpf projects, but in VSTO I can't.

Checked on Visual Studio 2019 and 2022.
Using search on this window don't find proper resource template.

What am I doing wrong?
Or maybe it's not VSTO's fault but something completely different?

[image: Screen with non VSTO solution and VSTO Solution]

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant way to get around this but at least it's a way around:

1. Add a user control to your folder
2. Open the XAML and remove all the user control references and make it look like below

   < ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   < /ResourceDictionary>
3. go to solution explorer and expand the subfiles in the XAML that you want as a resource and delete the .cs

[how to delete the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8m1.png)

Hope this helps